# Optimal n-tuple of integers fulfilling certain inequations

Tags: integers, maxima-minima

I am trying to find a set of integers $k_1, k_2, ..., k_n$ with $n\ge1$, that produces the minimal difference to a given $m$ (e.g. 1,000 or 1,000,000) in (1):

(1) $\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{k_i} - m \ge 0$ with $p_i$ being the i-th odd prime number (i.e. $p_1=3$),

(2) $log_3m \ge \sum_{i=1}^nk_i$ and

(3) $k_1\ge k_2\ge...\ge k_n\ge1$

Obviously there is always a minimum n-tuple, because n and $k_i$ have an upper limit due to condition (2) and therefore we have a finite set. So far my approach has been to calculate the minimum difference to m in (1) for n = 1, then for n = 2 etc and stop, if an increase in n leads to $k_n = 0$. I was wondering, if there is a better way to approach this problem than my trial and error method. Suggestions are much appreciated.
P.S.: I am not happy with the keyword `maxima-minima`, so feel free to add a more appropriate keyword.

Edit: I implemented now the suggestion from @ross-milikan, which has a lovely algorithmic structure. Only to avoid problems with accuracy limitations during the computation, I modified the initial approach in (1) to
(4) $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i log_3p_i - log_3m \ge 0$

Thanks for the helpful discussion, Ross.

Comment: Is the product in $(1)$ the thing you want close to $m$?  So for $m=11$ you would want $k_1=2,k_2=1$?

Comment: Exactly. The product should be close to m, i.e. the difference should be as small as possible, but not negative.

Comment: Just seen your edit: Actually for m=11, it would be $k_1=3$, because 27 is closer to 11 than 45. I corrected my description.

Comment: I missed that you do not allow $2$ here.

Comment: Yup all factors have to be of form `2i+1` and (3) is essential, so this makes each factor an odd prime number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be surprised if there is a better approach than searching, but here are some thoughts to guide the search.  Because the $k_i$ are decreasing your product is a product of things like primorials but skipping $2$.  We can define $q_i=k_i-k_{i+1}$ and your product becomes $3^{q_1}15^{q_2}105^{q_3}1155^{q_4}15015^{q_5}255255^{q_6}4849845^{q_7}\ldots$.  As these numbers are increasing so rapidly it is easy to find a maximum $n$.  Even for $m=10,000,000$ it is obvious we want $n$ no greater than $7$ because $q_1=1,q_7=1$ is much lower than $q_8=1$.  Now we can just search downwards, lowering $n$ and seeing if we can improve.  If we make $n=6$ we need to multiply $255255$ by about $40$, so $q_1=1,q_2=1,q_6=1$ becomes our new best estimate.

For a range even up to $m$ in the billions there will not be many choices.  It wouldn't be hard to just list and sort them, then look up the next one greater than $m$.

I find (if my handwork in a spreadsheet is correct) that there are only $140$ numbers up to $10,000,000$ that are candidates for $m$.  The start of a table is shown below.  The left column are the values of $m$ that are available.  The subsequent columns show the $q_i$ corresponding to each.
[image]

Comment: I like the  {k->q} transformation idea, makes the approach cleaner. Caveat from my side: The definition of $q_i$ is not correct, but I get the idea. Upvoted, but you won't see it, until I get enough credentials.

Comment: I think the definition of the $q_i$ is correct.  If you have $k_1=7, k_2=5, k_3=1,k_4=1$ I will have $q_1=2, q_2=4, q_3=0,q_4=1$ and I will get $3^215^41155^1=3^75^57\cdot 11$

Comment: Oh no, my bad. I thought yesterday that in your representation (a) $k_r = \sum_r^n q_i$ and (b) $q_n=0$, not realising that (a) is an equivalence and (b) is not true. Sorry for the confusion.